# Is there any PHP function to format time (not date)?

Tags: php, time

I have a mysql table field set as time type which stores data in the HH:mm:ss format. So when I list the data, it prints as, for example, 16:30:00. But I want to display hh:mm part only (not the seconds).

In case of datetime types, I can do date('H:i', '2010-03-16 16:30:00'). I mean I can retrieve any part. I wonder if there is any similar way like this for time only fields??

Please see, I can manipulate the time string to get rid of seconds in time part using str_replace, explode etc, I just wonder if there is any standard function there which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do this with PHP, you'd have to get a timestamp from the time first, e.g.

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime('16:30:00'));
```

will output `16:30`. [Strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will assume the time is for the current date then.

Answer (score 3):

You can let MySQL return the data in the format you want using [Date_Format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

edit: as [fireeyedboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165154/fireeyedboy) pointed out there's also a [TIME_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,format)  .. it expects date as first parameter but i have got only time ???

Comment: It also accepts a TIME value. If you pass a TIME and try to access the DATE-part (e.g. %Y-%m-%d %H:%i) MySQL "assumes" 0000-00-00

Comment: You just need to specify your time in the format and not the date Ex: DATE_FORMAT(date,'HH:MM:SS')

Comment: There is also a TIME_FORMAT function.

Comment: BTW: from what I remember, I don't believe DATE_FORMAT exepts a TIME value.

Comment: I just tried it on a 5.0.67-community-nt server, and date\_format() accepts a TIME value. ...but why use it if there is also time\_format()? Good catch.

Comment: hello all .. thanks for infor. Time_Format looks great for what I need .. but I'll be using a php function strtotime. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_field) AS tstamp FROM table;
```

Then you can use PHP's [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format it.

```
$time = date('H:i', $tstamp);
```